# I have two large columns, one 391k long and one 50k. I need to have the cells with the same data put next to eachother

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Both columns A & B have phone numbers. Each of the 50,000 column B does appear in the column A with 391,000 too.

I just want the 50,000 column B to have each number matched up with the same ROW as the 391k column A.

This way the same row for both column A and column B have the same value if the data is in both rows. If there is a phone number on the 391k list, but not on the 50k list, then in that row, column A would have a phone number, and column B would be blank.

Comment: You need to first sort both columns.  Best practice would be to sort at the time of insertion, rather than doing it on demand.  Once they are sorted, simply add rows to column B until the first record match.  Then, move to the next row in B and repeat (add more rows)

Comment: Aaaand your question is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move Column B data to Column D

Then in Column B, use the following formula cell (B2) as an example.
`=vlookup(A2,D:D,1,0)`

That will match the value in A with the list in column D. Copy and paste special values and you are done.

Comment: Would be slightly better if you had your `VLOOKUP()` inside an `IFERROR()` ^^ (for the blanks).

Comment: Thanks Jerry, yes the blanks now have n/a in there. Not a huge deal, but would have been better without. I can simply remove those now though.

Answer (score 0):

In cell C1 and copied down to the last phone number in column A:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$50000,A1)=0,"",A1)
```

Then hide column B.